# how avoid line breaks when after appending in an contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, html

i have this jquery script below to append an image to a contenteditable div. Howevr it adds a line break to the text, how do i avoid this?

```
$(".sm").live('click', function(){
      var src = $(this).attr('src');
      $("#shout").append("<img src="+src+" />");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

After you insert your elements, append some whitespace to each of them using `.after():`

```
$(".some-selector").after(" ");
```

Solution 2:

You could use map to put a single-space TextNode after each DIV:

```
$('.some-selector').detach().manipulate().map(function() {
    return [this, document.createTextNode(' ')];
}).appendTo('.container');
```

Comment: i am a bit confused. i would be grateful if you could use the selectors in my example. i am getting yours mixed up